# Integrated GPU passthrough performs better *without* hardware acceleration

Tags: gpu, linux-kvm, kodi, libvirt

First, some background on the iGPU passthrough since it might be relevant:

- One of my VMs should be able to play both audio and video over the motherboard's physical HDMI port. In my case I'm specifically using it for **Kodi**.
- I had actually already installed the necessary drivers in the **guest** earlier, for different reasons.
- The guest gets 2 virtual CPU cores with the same model as the host (`<cpu mode='host-passthrough'>`), which is an `Intel i5-7400`.
- The iGPU is an `Intel HD Graphics 630` with `Intel 200 Series PCH HD` for audio.
- The actual GPU device is in its own IOMMU group, but audio was in a group with SMBus/chipset devices. I had to edit my host's grub config so it contains the following, in order to "isolate" the audio device: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="... vfio-pci.ids=8086:a2f0 modprobe.blacklist=i2c_i801,i2c_smbus"`
- Then I just added `Host PCI Device`s through `virt-manager`. Passthrough is now completely functional.

Now, there's some weirdness regarding playback performance, even on some good ol' **h264 720p** stuff:

1. Before making any changes I started a video and Kodi says `Hardware decoding: Inactive` (when I press `o` to bring up some video information). However, playback actually is quite smooth and CPU load in the guest isn't too high: load averages of `1.53, 1.33, 1.24` after a few minutes of playing a very dynamic scene. Also, in the Kodi settings all the acceleration-related options are invisible, meaning it really doesn't detect any form of it being available. And indeed, when starting up there are some errors:

```
libva info: VA-API version 1.4.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
```

I'm not sure how it decided on that specific driver, I think it might just be trying the first one found in that directory. In any case, it's the wrong one so I ran:

```
$ export LIBVA_DRIVER_NAME=iHD
$ export LIBVA_DRIVERS_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri
$ vainfo 2>&1 | grep ^libva
libva info: VA-API version 1.4.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: User requested driver 'iHD'
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iHD_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_4
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
```

2. After restarting Kodi I now have VAAPI settings available to me, so I made sure to at least enable h264 and played the same video. However, both audio and video are **immediately extremely choppy**, even before seeking to the particular scene. After hitting the space bar on the keyboard to pause playback it still takes a good 5 seconds to actually pause. Load average for the last minute is immediately close to **3.0**. Pressing `o` now **does** mention acceleration is in fact being used.
3. Just to be certain I `unset` the exports and successfully verified it still plays smoothly with the previous setup. I can reliably reproduce both these behaviours.

My guess is that it being an iGPU, maybe explicitly using VAAPI is unnecessary and it uses something more optimised by default? Or maybe the fact that I'm also using audio instead of just using GPU power causes complications for VAAPI?